# How to find column of control inside grid?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

In my asp grid few columns are template fields and few columns are binding from DataTable.
I set **Autogenearte=true**. So total 
**columns =static columns+DataTable columns** 
.I am reordering columns on row created event.

My problem is among static columns i need to disable some columns depending on some 
conditions. I need to identify column no of controls inside static template fields. So that i can set 
e.Row.Cells[7].CssClass = "hiddencol";
But how can i get the column no

i tried

```
int colNo=0;   
for(int count=0;count<e.Row.Cells.count;count++)
{ 
   Button btn=(Button) e.Row.Cells[Count].FindControl("txtCol");
   if(btn!=null)
   colNo=count;
}
```

But i am not getting column no. It is satisfying for all columns.

Comment: It is best to control CSS with javascript.

Comment: @LIUFA In this case the information which determines if the cell should be hidden may be on the server.  It's more efficient to send the markup to the browser as it should be as opposed to running code to hide stuff after the page is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your intentions, how about something like the following.  It worked for my test.

Grid

```
 <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound">
    <Columns>

        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Static Col 1"></asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Static Col 2" >
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnTest" Text="Hide Me"/>

            </ItemTemplate>

        </asp:TemplateField>

    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Code Behind

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GridView1.DataSource = GetData();
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }



    private DataTable GetData()
    {
        // get some data and return it
    }

    protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            if (HideCell(e.Row.RowIndex))
            {
                var cell = e.Row.Cells.Cast<TableCell>().FirstOrDefault(c => c.FindControl("btnTest") != null);
                if (cell != null)
                {
                    cell.CssClass = "hidden";
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private bool HideCell(int rowNum)
    {
        return rowNum%2 == 0;
    }
```